# Codeigniter user registration: split login fail condition in 2 conditions to cover "account inactive" case

Tags: php, codeigniter, registration, login-script

I have made a **Registration and Login** application with Codeigniter 3.

When someone fills the *Registration form* and submits it successfully, the "active" column of the "users" table receives the value 0, as visible in the image bellow:

[image]

Users will have to activate their accounts before being able to sign in.

In the Signin.php controller I have the `signin()` function:

```
public function signin()
{  
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
  $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
  if ($this->form_validation->run())
  {
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $this->load->model('Usermodel');
    $current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password, $active);
    // Set the current user's data
    if ($current_user) {
     $this->session->set_userdata(
       array(
        'user_id' => $current_user->id,
        'user_email' => $current_user->email,
        'user_first_name' => $current_user->fname,
        'is_logged_in' => TRUE
        )
       );
     redirect('home');  
   } else {
      $this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Incorrect email or password");
      redirect('signin'); 
    }
  }
  else
  {
   $this->load->view('signin');
 }
}
```

I want, instead of the line `$this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Incorrect email or password");` in the code above, to be able to "split" the login failure condition in 2: **Incorrect email or Password** *and* **account has not been activated**.

```
if (condition here) {
      $this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Your account has not been activated");
    } else {
      $this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Incorrect email or password");
 }
```

My **question**: what should I put instead of `condition here` in the code above?

More specifically: how do I say: if the "active" column has the value 0 do `$this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Your account has not been activated");`?

The user_login() function inside the **Usermodel**:

```
public function user_login($email, $password, $active) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', ['email' => $email, 'password' => md5($password), 'active' => 1]);
        return $query->row();
}
```

UPDATE:

I came up with this:

```
public function signin()
  {  
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
  $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
  if ($this->form_validation->run())
  {
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $this->load->model('Usermodel');
    $current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);
      // If we find a user
    if ($current_user) {
      // If the user found is active
      if ($current_user->active == 1) {
        $this->session->set_userdata(
         array(
          'user_id' => $current_user->id,
          'user_email' => $current_user->email,
          'user_first_name' => $current_user->fname,
          'user_active' => $current_user->active,
          'is_logged_in' => TRUE
          )
         );
        redirect('home');  
      } else {
        // If the user found is NOT active
        $this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Your account has not been activated");
        redirect('signin'); 
      }
    } else {
      // If we do NOT find a user
      $this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Incorrect email or password");
      redirect('signin'); 
    }
  }
  else
  {
   $this->load->view('signin');
 }
}
```

but there is a flaw in it because even when the *email and password are correct*, but the user is *inactive*, the message is: "Incorrect email or password" Instead of "Your account has not been activated".

Comment: change `if($current_user->active == 1)` to `if($current_user['active'] == 1)` because the function return the result as array not object.

Comment: I just did and it gives this error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`.

Comment: use `return $query->row_array();` in model function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the check for active from `user_login` function in model. As you are already checking id the user is active or not in your controller. It should not impact your working.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('users', ['email' => $email, 'password' => md5($password)]);
```

**EDIT:**

Well elaborated answer Contribution by **JayAdra** in the Codeigniter forum [here](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-69160.html)

This is because your first if statement is:

```
if ($current_user) {
```

Which will return false for an inactive user, as your query is:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('users', ['email' => $email, 'password' => md5($password), 'active' => 1]);
```

Notice, the check for "active" => 1, meaning it won't return any records for inactive users.

So your first if statement returns false, hence going to the else clause which has:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Incorrect email or password");
```

So you probably need to check if the user is active first, before checking if their username/password is correct.

I'd suggest splitting your "user_login" function into two distinct functions. One to check if the user is active, and one to test the user/pass combo.

Lastly, I noticed you're storing your password as md5 strings... this is a bad idea. It's not secure. Use bcrypt or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
/***************************************/ // model function
function user_login($email,$password)
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('table_name');
    $this->db->where(array('email'=>$email,'password'=>$password));
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if(!$query->num_rows())
        return false;
    return $query->row_array();
}
/***************************************/ // controller
public function signin()
{  
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()){
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->load->model('Usermodel');
        $current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);
        // If we find a user
        if ($current_user) {
            // If the user found is active
            if ($current_user['active'] == 1) {
                $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                    'user_id' => $current_user['id'],
                    'user_email' => $current_user['email'],
                    'user_first_name' => $current_user['fname'],
                    'user_active' => $current_user['active'],
                    'is_logged_in' => TRUE
                ));
                redirect('home');  
            }else {
                // If the user found is NOT active
                $this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Your account has not been activated");
                redirect('signin'); 
            }
        }else {
            // If we do NOT find a user
            $this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Incorrect email or password");
            redirect('signin'); 
        }
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view('signin');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put your controller code in the context of _my_ Signin controller code. I have a lot of code and changing the variable names would produce a lot of errors. Thanks!